# jquery each function gives value 0

Tags: jquery, load, each

I have a script in jquery which sets the iframe height by checking the content height of the iframe. But it sets the height of the first iframe content height on both iframes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $("iframe").load(function() {
    var iframeHeight = $("iframe").contents().height();
    $("iframe").height(iframeHeight);
  });

});
```

Changing to "each function" instead of "load" generates value 0.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $("iframe").each(function() {
    var iframeHeight = $("iframe").contents().height();
    $("iframe").height(iframeHeight);
  });

});
```

Why doesn´t each-function work?

Thanks

Magnus

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your quick answers! This is a tab solution with attached iframes to it.

I added a click function for the tab with the hidden (display:none) iframe. I ALMOST works...

When I click the "second" tab it does not change height of iframe on the first click! But if I click the same tab a second time i change the height to iframe content. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $("iframe").load(function() {
          var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().height()
          $(this).height(iframeHeight);
          console.log(iframeHeight);
     });

     $(".tab").click(function() {
          $(".current_tab .iframe").css("display","block");
          var iframeHeight = $(".current_tab .iframe").contents().height()
          $(".current_tab .iframe").height(iframeHeight);
          console.log(iframeHeight);
     });

});
</script>
```

Comment: In your each function, change `$("iframe")` to `$(this)`.  When calling `$("iframe")` Jquery will always return the first instance it finds in the DOM.  Calling `$(this)` will return whatever element is currently being evaluated.

Comment: Check [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imoshtokill/nf9pxyh0/) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure this is a good solution. But this is what I ended up with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $("iframe").load(function() {
          var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().height()
          $(this).height(iframeHeight);
          console.log(iframeHeight);
     });

    $(document).on("click",".tab",function(){
          $(".current_tab .iframe").css("display","block");
          var iframeHeight = $(".current_tab .iframe").contents().height()
          $(".current_tab .iframe").height(iframeHeight);
          console.log(iframeHeight);
     });

});
</script>
```

Feel free to comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using "this" instead of "iframe" for the selector inside the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $("iframe").load(function() {
    var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().height();
    $(this).height(iframeHeight);
  });

});
```

That should work

Comment: "This" :-) solution works. Just partly for me though. It gives the height of the two iframes. But for the iframe that has css display:none it gives 0 height. I thought the each function should solve that but it gives value 0 to both iframes.